# MS Access Update Query with Date columns

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am using a staging table in ms access to catch an excel report with daily labor information. Its just a bulk upload form and a button with a click event. With every upload the staging table gets deleted and recreated. The first 3 headers are the same for every report. The date fields store hours worked for the day, but since this is a weekly report the fields for the dates change.

ChargeNumber,p_code,e_ID,date1,date2,date3,date4,date5

I've managed to write an update query in ms access to update a labor table from a staging table, but I have to manually change the columns for the dates. I've considered capturing the header information into an array and parsing out the information, but my coding strengths are limited to TSQL and my TSQL skills are still improving....I am sure there is a better way to dynamically handle this....I am just not seeing it.

`INSERT INTO Labor2 ( ChargeNumber, e_ID, dateworked, p_Code, hoursworked )
SELECT I.ChargeNumber, I.e_ID, "2017-11-07" AS dateworked, I.p_code, I.[2017-11-07]
FROM tbl_Import AS I
WHERE (((I.[2017-11-07]) Is Not Null));`

I am not looking for anyone to answer my question with a solution. I am looking for a path to traverse so I can figure out my own problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have exactly five columns, you can use

```
INSERT INTO Labor2 ( ChargeNumber, e_ID, dateworked, p_Code, hoursworked ) 
select * 
from tbl_Import
```

and then filter in the next step instead. A bit dirty, but simple.

Comment: Sam, Thank you for your suggestion, however the issue that the dates do change. I am having trouble creating a solution to overcome the changing date fields and switching them to a record entry for example:

Comment: 12345, em3345,1/1/21018,15,2.5, is the record entry I am attempting to achieve. but the "1/1/2018" is a column header.